# Display issue with Parallel RGB

Tags: display

I'm having trouble with a parallel RGB output to a display from the compute module. I think it's a hardware issue with the board assembly as I have two of the same layout boards with only one having the issue. What I'm hoping for is that someone with more display experience could help me understand what could cause the weird output seen in the attached picture. I'm getting what looks like solid red, green, or blue pixels around areas of color or brightness transition.

Thanks,

David

[image]

Comment: How is the display connected to the RPi? Do you have two Pis, one which works and the other which does not? Or two screens? If Pis, are they both updated? `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Ah, that is the usual the RGB "colour convergence" problem.  If the warranty period is not over, send it back for replacement.  All these years whenever I buy a new colour mon, I would ask the shopkeeper to use the mon test program to carefully by eyes to check if there is any "dead" spot, and the separate colour bands are sharp, no overlapping, blurring etc.  For colour scopes, the user adjustment is all digital, so my knowledge and skills are all out of date. :)